# A 30*30 bmp image file, why does it have 2756 pixel data?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, bmp

I have a bmp file which size is 30*30.
In python, I use
`im = Image.open("big.bmp")
rgb_img_data = list(im.getdata())
len = len(rgb_img_data)`
get 900
So I guess the real image data should be 900*3 = 2700 (r,g,b)
But I read the image data with read() function.
Get rid of the header and footer, I get 2756 data items like this,
`11110101`
(I convert it to binary, '11110101' is one data item, I get 2756 data items like this)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because image files have header information, it's not 100% pixel data there, that wouldn't work.

And the header for a (version 3, see [BITMAPV3INFOHEADER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)) BMP is 56 bytes.

This is why you're typically using libraries to read bitmaps, it saves you from having to deal with the internals of the file format.

Comment: I know that the bmp file have a header. I have already gotten rid of them, just left pure image color data.  010001....(the header)...110011001100(image color data: 2756)...0000...(the footer)  The total number of image data is 2816.

Answer (score 1):

From the wiki:

The bits representing the bitmap pixels are packed in rows. The size of each row is rounded up to a multiple of 4 bytes (a 32-bit DWORD) by padding.
For images with height > 1, multiple padded rows are stored consecutively, forming a Pixel Array.

Together with color mapping, compression techniques makes your calculation invalid. Hopes this helps.